# Реализация стека из указателей в C#

Tags: c#, указатели, стек

Пытаюсь реализовать стек с использованием указателей.
Пробовал сделать так (пока набросок):

```
    Node* head;

    unsafe struct Node 
    {
        public Int32 Value;
        public Node* Next;
    }        

    public LinkedStack()
    {
        head = null;
    }

    public void Add(Int32 value)
    {
        // Создаётся новый элемент стека, который ссылается на предыдущую "голову"
        Node newNode = new Node();
        newNode.Next = head;
        newNode.Value = value;

        head = &newNode;
    }

    public Int32 Peek()
    {
        return head->Value;
    }
```

При этом любое обращение к head->Value вне блока Add (к примеру в блоке Peek()) возвращает семизначные и более числа, которые не были занесены в стек.

Но при вынесении переменной newNode в переменные класса следующим образом и обращение к ней используя fixed работает нормально и возвращает корректные значения:

```
    Node* head;
    Node newNode;

    unsafe struct Node 
    {
        public Int32 Value;
        public Node* Next;
    }        

    public LinkedStack()
    {
        head = null;
    }

    public void Add(Int32 value)
    {
        fixed (Node* pNewNode = &newNode) // Необходимый костыль
        {
            pNewNode->Next = head;
            pNewNode->Value = value;

            // Меняем указатель головы на новый элемент
            head = pNewNode;
        }
    }

    public Int32 Peek()
    {
        return head->Value;
    }
```

Не могу понять в чём проблема. Почему после окончания блока Add значение Value меняется на произвольное другое? А при использовании fixed значение хранится нормально.

Comment: Извините, не по делу: а зачем вы это пишете? Ну эти указатели, стек? Какой практический выхлоп планируется от всего этого?

Comment: @Bulson В лабораторной была задача сделать стек с использованием указателей на любом языке. В то время я изучал C#, поэтому мой выбор был очевиден =)

Comment: Как успехи? Сдали лабораторку? Ответ VladD вам помог? Если да, то закройте, пожалуйста, этот вопрос, поставьте галку слева от ответа.

Comment: @Bulson В конце концов я просто сделал через классы, так и сдал =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы делаете неправильно практически всё, вам стоит освежить в памяти начальные главы [учебника по C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/416584/10105).

Напомню базовые вещи. Структуры в C#, в отличие от классов, являются объектами-значениями. Они аллоцируются на стеке* (да, `new` в C# означает не то же самое, что в C++), копируются по значению при передаче из функции, и умирают вместе с фреймом, в котором были аллоцированы. Отсюда следует, что указатель на структуру, не находящуюся в «долгоживущей» памяти, **не имеет смысла**.

Это объясняет проблемы первой реализации `Add`.

Далее, любой объект, не закреплённый (например, при помощи блока `fixed`) в памяти, может в любой момент быть перемещён сборщиком мусора. Поэтому указатель на не закреплённый в памяти объект (в отличие от *ссылки*) также **не имеет смысла**.

Но центральная проблема второй реализации функции `Add` не в этом. Она в том, что вы записываете новые данные в один и тот же экземпляр `newNode`, и новые значения затирают старые. Этого пока не заметно, поскольку у вас в коде есть лишь возможность просмотреть через `Peek` один элемент, текущую голову списка.

Я бы предложил не использовать `unsafe`-указатели в C#-коде, если это не является жизненно необходимым. Для их использования нужно реально хорошо понимать работу GC. Пока вы этого не знаете — лучше пользоваться стандартными средствами.

```
class LinkedStack
{
    Node head = null;

    class Node 
    {
        public int Value;
        public Node Next;
    }        

    public void Add(int value)
    {
        // Создаётся новый элемент стека, который ссылается на предыдущую "голову"
        Node newNode = new Node();
        newNode.Next = head;
        newNode.Value = value;

        head = newNode;
    }

    public int Peek()
    {
        return head.Value;
    }
}
```

---

*Строго говоря, [не обязательно, но в первом приближении это так](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail-part-one/).